# How to transmit video and internet over same lan

Tags: lan

I was able to extend my hdmi cable over 50 meters using my hdmi lan extender.

I want to know is there any way by which i can pass my internet through the same cable, so that the recieving end (tv), i can split it. Then the  can get the video signals (hdmi) as well as internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that would be possible. You MAY hack a solution if the extender only uses certain wires/pins, maybe tell us the model? I'd personally recommend running another wire or use Wi-Fi internet

Comment: If you're using extenders that support [HDMI 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4) the ethernet channel in the HDMI stream itself may make it through. Devices on both ends need to actually support ethernet over HDMI though (which is rare).

Answer (score 1):

HDMI extenders use the same kind of cables as Ethernet LANs use, but they don't actually do Ethernet LAN signaling, and their signaling cannot coexist with Ethernet LAN signaling. So they should never be called "HDMI over LAN". They're just "HDMI over Cat 5e UTP with RJ45 connectors".